# Error while installing mysql server

Tags: server, apt, package-management, mysql

I am getting the following error while install mysql

Steps I did : Downloaded apt file from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
run this command

```
sudo dpkg -i path
```

In that there is no option to select 5.5 so I selected 5.6
then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but it gives error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

/etc/apt/sources.list : http://pastebin.com/PwJX2pi6

/etc/apt/sources.list.d :

```
kubuntu-ci-stable-trusty.list
kubuntu-ci-stable-trusty.list.save
pwntools-binutils-trusty.list
pwntools-binutils-trusty.list.save
rvm-smplayer-trusty.list
webupd8team-java-trusty.list
webupd8team-java-trusty.list.save
```

Comment: Why are you not installing it from the repositories? Why get the one from http://dev.mysql.com? Do you really need the latest version for some reason? Your problems would disappear if you just installed from the repositories.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am new to linux. Can you say how to do that or any link to tutorial? I followed some tutorial and was installing.

Comment: Ugh, it looks like your first command has changed your repositories. You will need to undo the change. Please [edit] your question and post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. You need to remove the mysql repository added by the first command.  Once you've done that, you can install with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` (which is all you needed in the first place).

Comment: Edited the post. How can I remove mysql repository?

Comment: Try this `sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server`